# Caption size - beamer

Tags: latex, caption, beamer

I have the following code on a beamer:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer} %[handout]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \tiny
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{\tiny Individual stocks risk-reallocation}
    \hspace*{-1.0cm}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
    some table here
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The issue with this code is that although I manage to make the title size "tiny" I don't seem to manage to make the word "Table" on the caption tiny as well. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer has its own mechanism to change the font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %[handout]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Individual stocks risk-reallocation}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
    some table here
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can have a look at the other stackexchange platform https://tex.stackexchange.com/ , were ´TeX´ related questions can be asked.

In your case, the code starting in line 4 should read like:

```
\usepackage[font=small, justification=centering]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\captionsetup{font=tiny}
```

This will create captions of size ´tiny´.

I found the following answer quite useful for my presentation:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172158/change-the-font-of-table-caption